# See who last changed a specific line in a Git repo

Tags: git, blame, git-blame

I have use `git blame` and `git log file.py` to find changes, but is there a way to see the changes on a specific line on a file? For example: Line 84 on file index.html.

Comment: Use `git blame <filename>`

Comment: is there a way to include the specific line I want to look in git command. Maybe something like. git blame <filename> 84. idk

Comment: The `-L <start>,<end>` option specifies a line range to show. You can `man git-blame` for more info.

Answer (score 8):

Very simple:

```
git blame -L 84,84 index.html
```

Comment: this is a very direct and simple answer to a simple question - the duplicate is much more complicated, this just works

Comment: The question was wrongly marked as a duplicate. The correct answer to the other question involves `git log`, this one uses `git blame`. Two completely different commands that generate completely different output.